# Ethernet connection takes 90 seconds to become available (Solution: Set Npcap to autostart)

Tags: windows-7, networking, ethernet

When I boot my Windows 7 PC, or when I disable and enable my Ethernet connection, it takes exactly 90 seconds for internet to become available. During that time the status is shown as normal (not "identifying").

During that time there are zero packets received or sent. Then, after 90 seconds suddenly there's a burst of traffic and the internet comes on. It works reliably from that point on.

I then disabled the Windows Media Player Sharing Service which was suggested somewhere on the web. Now there is still a 90 seconds window where there is no internet. But at least there are packets being sent. Just zero received packets still.

I tested the cable with another cable. It did not make a difference. The router is a normal ISP provided router. It's a very common device and other devices in the network are not affected. Also, there is only Windows Firewall enabled in a default configuration. No other security software.

What could cause this issue?

Comment: try a new ethernet cable, try a different port for that cable in the router, let me know if that makes any difference

Comment: @JohnnyVegas can it really be the cable if the connection works totally fine otherwise? Also, the software change I described made a difference that cannot be due to hardware. I'd be open to try a different cable but this cable is routed through parts of the room that are very hard to reach...

Comment: @boot4life - It is worth a try and it eliminates one of the many factors.  Please edit your question, instead of submitting a comment, once you have tested another cable.  You don't have to route the cable normally in order to test it.

Comment: Maybe some kind of network loop detection logic on the switch side?

Comment: I have made further edits. The cable is fine and other devices are not affected.

Comment: What security software are you running? I ran into an issue a few years ago where a very famous site filtering software would do an update everyday at the same time and during the update, no websites were accessible. Perhaps yours is updating when initially connected.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean no security software except for Windows Firewall which I have not touched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried everything mentioned in this question. Also, I tried resetting the network stack entirely. This did not help.

I then disabled stuff here:

[image]

And it started working. **By successively enabling items again I found that the Npcap item was causing the issue.** (On this screenshot it is not visible because I already uninstalled it.) I did have the latest Npcap version already. I then reinstalled Wireshark and Npcap which did not help directly but:

**When I set no autostart in the Npcap installer then the problem occurs. When I enable autostart the problem goes away.**

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities I can think of and which can be causing this issue but they are more relevant to enterprise rather then home/soho deployments:

1. The switch is configured with leaf nodes having STP enabled. This usually causes 15-30 seconds of delay before switch enables traffic forwarding on newly linked port. This can be rectified by disabling STP on leaf port altogether or at least enabling "port-fast" mode.
2. 802.1x is enabled on a port. Port will not forward traffic (or will forward it only to enclave VLAN) before the port is authorized. Authentication and authorization is handled by radius server and 90 seconds looks excessively long (but I've seen cheap switches where 802.1x is really slow).

SG-200-08 (mentioned in the other answer) may be both STP and 802.1x capable as this seems to be a clone of SLM2008 which is. Please check your switch configuration.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed authentication was enabled for me which cost be another 1-2 seconds while the adapter was attempting to authenticate (as evidenced by the status text). I got rid of that. For the solution to my problem see my answer if you are interested. Again thanks for your help.